# Can First-class functions in Scala be a concern for allocating a large PermGen Space in JVM?

Tags: function, scala, jvm, permgen, first-class

Regarding first-class functions in Scala, it is written in the book Programming by Scala:

> A function literal is compiled into a
>   class that when instantiated at
>   run-time is a function value.

When there will be many first-class functions used in a program, will this affect the JVM's PermGen space? because instead of simple functions the compiler is generating classes for each variation of the function value (e.g. in the case of varied definitions of partially applied functions).

Comment: Scala is a statically-typed language and therefore it should qualify to be used in large projects which may impose space considerations for the jvm process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory profile is certainly going to be different than that of normal Java programs, though you can tune pretty much any memory parameter on the JVM.

All I can say, however, is that in one year of deep involvement in the Scala community, I have *never* seen anyone complain about this.

Comment: take your word on it for now :)
and btw totally inspired by your blog.

Comment: Thanks. I should update it more often... it's not for a lack of material.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have substantiation for this, but my feeling is that if you're writing any non-trivial program, the amount of space taken up for your program's "real" data will vastly dwarf the amount of space taken up by a few extra function-as-class definitions.

In other words, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a proven mathematical fact that the number of classes you generate with first-class functions will be able to asymptotically approach, but never surpass, the number of compiled classes in the full Spring distribution.  Don't worry, those pioneers will deal with the permgen issues first!

Comment: I can't upvote it in good conscience, but it _was_ funny! :-)

Comment: Just a joke.  Please don't take seriously.

Comment: haha, good one! I got it now :-)
worth posting on some place like http://www.geekherocomic.com/